# Changing XML tag value using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm writing my first powershell script and trying to change an Xml tag value as per the code below. I'm getting an error:

**Cannot set "Version" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.**

```
Function Get-AutomaticPackageVersion() {
   $mayor = 1
   $minor = 0
   $build = 15
   $revision = 0

   return ("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $mayor, $minor, $build, $revision) 
}

Function Set-AppxManifestVersion($file, $version) {
   $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
   $node = $xml.Package.Identity
   $node.Version = Get-AutomaticPackageVersion $args[1]
   $xml.Save($file)
}

$version = Get-AutomaticPackageVersion
Set-AppxManifestVersion $manifestFile  $version
```

Comment: Thank you very much PetSerAI! It works.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Can you elaborate on why that makes a difference?  Doesn't `Get-AutomaticPackageVersion()` return a string regardless of whether or not you explicitly call `return`?

Comment: @JasonBoyd IIRC, in PowerShell v2 `return` keyword wrap returned objects into `PSObject`.